# How to push a file from Azure Data Factory onto a MS Teams Channel

Tags: azure, microsoft-teams, azure-data-factory

At the moment, I am having to routinely manually upload a file onto a Teams Channel.

I have managed to create a pipeline to upload the file into my Azure Data Lake. I would now like to push the file from my Azure environment to my Teams Channel. I have found that webhooks cannot work with files and that bots can send files in the chat but not "Upload" them into a channel.

Is there a way to upload files from Azure to MS Teams using Data Factory or other alternatives?

Thank you.

Comment: No, we can't achieve it by Data Factory.

Answer (score 0):

The most appropriate way to **partially** achieve this would be to use a Teams [Adaptive Card](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/design-effective-cards?tabs=desktop) Connector but I couldn't find any way to easily set it up. It seems quite complex. Second option would be to use a Teams Post Message Connector from Azure Logic App but unfortunately it might not yet support attachments but you can send links to files stored elsewhere (SharePoint, Blob etc). Here's what you can try in the meantime.

In ADF:

1. Create a Copy Activity that will send the files to a Storage.
2. Create a Web Activity that will send a notification to a Logic App when the pipeline. You only need to use this as a trigger for the Logic App.

In Logic Apps:

1. Create an HTTP Connector that will receive the pipeline run information the files using the Azure Storage Blob `Create blob` action.
2. After that, create a Microsoft Teams `Post a message (V3)` Teams Connector, choose your Team and Channel
3. Use the `Get blob content using path` action to get a URL to the file - you might need to construct this URL.
4. Create your message using variables from the above connector and parse a link to the file to be downloaded.

Depending on the content of the file, you could also try to retrieve partial content and display it in the message body directly (if you can consider that an alternative for you).

I've not tried using the Adaptive Card Connector but I know it does give you a far richer dynamic experience. You would need to spend some time to design a custom card solution. Use this [playground](https://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net/) to see if it's something you can explore in the future.

The flow is as follows and kinda runs in parallel:

ADF Pipeline runs > ADF Copy Activity saves file in Blob storage
ADF Pipeline runs > ADF Web Activity triggers Logic App HTTP Connector > Logic App retrieves file from Blob storage > Sends a message to a Teams channel with a link to the file.

Here are all the supported [Teams Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/teams/).